# Why it is called "The Next Three Days"?

Tags: title, the-next-three-days

I really enjoyed this movie. It was an excellent thriller about a couple's escape with their son to Canada.

I was confused, however, by the title: [*The Next Three Days*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Next_Three_Days). The movie is a remake of an older French film with a more logical title: [*Anything For Her*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anything_for_Her). So, where did the new title come from?

Comment: Don't they run to Rio and not Canada?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The title of the movie refers to the basic source of dramatic tension in the movie. John is planning to break his wife, Lara, out of prison, and has spent some time coming up with a detailed plan on how to do so.

However, he soon learns that Lara is being transferred to another, more secure prison, he realizes his plans aren't going to work. So he has 72 hours -- three days -- to come up with another plan and execute it.

The movie then tells the story of that "next three days" in John and Lara's life.